# How does the expression "float | 0" produces an integer?

Tags: javascript, operators, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

Please describe how does `5.55 | 0` produces `5` in JavaScript. I want to know what is happening in this bitwise operating. Thanks!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_OR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operands of bitwise operations are always converted to signed 32-bit integers in big-endian order and in two's complement format.

That would be

```
    00000000000000000000000000000101
or  00000000000000000000000000000000
------------------------------------ 
    00000000000000000000000000000101
```

Comment: Aren't they actually endian-neutral?

Comment: Hm true, maybe it makes it easier to understand the shift operations.

Answer (score 2):

The bitwise operators in Javascript automatically coerce their arguments to 32-bit integer values by dropping the fraction and any high-order bits beyond 32. So

```
5.55 | 0
```

is treated like:

```
5 | 0
```